# UIPageViewController delegate method not called with scroll transition style

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I use a `UIPageViewController` to scroll vertically to show my data. I create it like this:

```
- (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    if (!_pageViewController) {
        NSDictionary *options = @{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: @(0)};
        _pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:options];
        _pageViewController.delegate = self;
        _pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    }

    return _pageViewController;
}
```

When my `UIPageViewController` show the last page, I want to scroll it up and trigger an action to load more data. But none of the `UIPageViewController` delegate or datasource methods were called.

But if I change the `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`, `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` and some other delegate and datasource methods were called as expected.

So is this a bug of `UIPageViewController`? How can I fix it?